# java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException Android

Tags: java, android

I am replacing part of a string as follows

```
biblebook.replaceAll("[{\"-bnumber\":\"1\",\"-bname\":\"Genesis\",\"CHAPTER\":","[");
```

but my log shows the following error

```
09-25 16:33:47.421: W/System.err(5116): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Missing closing bracket in character class near index 46:
    09-25 16:33:47.421: W/System.err(5116): [{"-bnumber":"1","-bname":"Genesis","CHAPTER":
    09-25 16:33:47.421: W/System.err(5116):                                               ^
    09-25 16:33:47.421: W/System.err(5116):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
    09-25 16:33:47.421: W/System.err(5116):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:400)
    09-25 16:33:47.429: W/System.err(5116):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:383)
    09-25 16:33:47.429: W/System.err(5116):     at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:374)
    09-25 16:33:47.429: W/System.err(5116):     at java.lang.String.replaceAll(String.java:1784)
    09-25 16:33:47.429: W/System.err(5116):     at .Index$loadingTask.doInBackground(Index.java:383)
```

any idea ?

UPDATE this is part of my string

> [{"-bnumber":"1","-bname":"Genesis","CHAPTER":[{"-cnumber":"1","VERS":[{"-vnumber":"1","#text":"Au
>   commencement, Dieu créa les cieux et la
>   terre."},{"-vnumber":"2","#text":"La terre était informe et vide: il y
>   avait des ténèbres à la surface de l'abîme, et l'esprit de Dieu se
>   mouvait au-dessus des eaux."},{"-vnumber":"3","#text":"Dieu dit: Que
>   la lumière soit! Et la lumière fut."},{"-vnumber":"4","#text":"Dieu
>   vit que la lumière était bonne; et Dieu sépara la lumière d'avec les
>   ténèbres."},{"-vnumber":"5","#text":"Dieu appela la lumière jour, et
>   il appela les ténèbres nuit. Ainsi, il y eut un soir, et il y eut un
>   matin: ce fut le premier jour."},{"-vnumber":"6","#text":"Dieu dit:
>   Qu'il y ait une étendue entre les eaux, et qu'elle sépare les eaux
>   d'avec les eaux."},{"-vnumber":"7","#text":"Et Dieu fit l'étendue, et
>   il sépara les eaux qui sont au-dessous de l'étendue d'avec les eaux
>   qui sont au-dessus de l'étendue. Et cela fut
>   ainsi."},{"-vnumber":"8","#text":"Dieu appela l'étendue ciel. Ainsi,
>   il y eut un soir, et il y eut un matin: ce fut le second
>   jour."},{"-vnumber":"9","#text":"Dieu dit: Que les eaux qui sont
>   au-dessous du ciel se rassemblent en un seul lieu, et que le sec
>   paraisse. Et cela fut ainsi."},{"-vnumber":"10","#text":"Dieu appela
>   le sec terre, et il appela l'amas des eaux mers. Dieu vit que cela
>   était bon."},{"-vnumber":"11","#text":"Puis Dieu dit: Que la terre
>   produise de la verdure, de l'herbe portant de la semence, des arbres
>   fruitiers donnant du fruit selon leur espèce et ayant en eux leur
>   semence sur la terre. Et cela fut
>   ainsi."},{"-vnumber":"12","#text":"La terre produisit de la verdure,
>   de l'herbe portant de la semence selon son espèce, et des arbres
>   donnant du fruit et ayant en eux leur semence selon leur espèce. Dieu
>   vit que cela était bon."},{"-vnumber":"13","#text":"Ainsi, il y eut un
>   soir, et il y eut un matin: ce fut le troisième
>   jour."},{"-vnumber":"14","#text":"Dieu dit: Qu'il y ait des luminaires
>   dans l'étendue du ciel, pour séparer le jour d'avec la nuit; que ce
>   soient des signes pour marquer les époques, les jours et les
>   années;"},{"-vnumber":"15","#text":"et qu'ils servent de luminaires
>   dans l'étendue du ciel, pour éclairer la terre. Et cela fut
>   ainsi."},{"-vnumber":"16","#text":"Dieu fit les deux grands
>   luminaires, le plus grand luminaire pour présider au jour, et le plus
>   petit luminaire pour présider à la nuit; il fit aussi les
>   étoiles."},{"-vnumber":"17","#text":"Dieu les plaça dans l'étendue du
>   ciel, pour éclairer la terre,"},{"-vnumber":"18","#text":"pour
>   présider au jour et à la nuit, et pour séparer la lumière d'avec les
>   ténèbres. Dieu vit que cela était
>   bon."},{"-vnumber":"19","#text":"Ainsi, il y eut un soir, et il y eut
>   un matin: ce fut le quatrième jour."},{"-vnumber":"20","#text":"Dieu
>   dit: Que les eaux produisent en abondance des animaux vivants, et que
>   des oiseaux volent sur la terre vers l'étendue du
>   ciel."},{"-vnumber":"21","#text":"Dieu créa les grands poissons et
>   tous les animaux vivants qui se meuvent, et que les eaux produisirent
>   en abondance selon leur espèce; il créa aussi tout oiseau ailé selon
>   son espèce. Dieu vit que cela était
>   bon."},{"-vnumber":"22","#text":"Dieu les bénit, en disant: Soyez
>   féconds, multipliez, et remplissez les eaux des mers; et que les
>   oiseaux multiplient sur la terre."},{"-vnumber":"23","#text":"Ainsi,
>   il y eut un soir, et il y eut un matin: ce fut le cinquième
>   jour."},{"-vnumber":"24","#text":"Dieu dit: Que la terre produise des
>   animaux vivants selon leur espèce, du bétail, des reptiles et des
>   animaux terrestres, selon leur espèce. Et cela fut
>   ainsi."},{"-vnumber":"25","#text":"Dieu fit les animaux de la terre
>   selon leur espèce, le bétail selon son espèce, et tous les reptiles de
>   la terre selon leur espèce. Dieu vit que cela était
>   bon."},{"-vnumber":"26","#text":"Puis Dieu dit: Faisons l'homme à
>   notre image, selon notre ressemblance, et qu'il domine sur les
>   poissons de la mer, sur les oiseaux du ciel, sur le bétail, sur toute

Comment: My comment is off-topic but I think that `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(biblebook)` would fit your need.

Comment: yes but then when say jsonArray.getString("CHAPTER"); i dont get all the items of chapter

Comment: `[` opens a character class, which is not closed afterward. If you don't actually want to open a class, escape the `[`

Comment: I don't know this library very much but you probably need to call something like `getJSONArray("CHAPTER");` as the result is not a String but an array.

Comment: yes my CHAPTER TAG  contains an atrribute, when i use getJSONArray("CHAPTER"); it escapes the attribute and returns only an arrays of element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to escape the square brackets (`[` and `]`) using double backslash (`\\`), as they have a function in regexp... (edit: and of course the curly brackets too `{` `}`)

```
biblebook.replaceAll("\\[\\{\"-bnumber\":\"1\",\"-bname\":\"Genesis\",\"CHAPTER\":","\\[");
```

Also: I find it helps me to use an online regex checker [like this](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) as it makes work much quicker

Comment: getting error : java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Error in {min,max} interval near index 4: after applying your solution

Comment: aligato ppeterka  (y)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to replace that exact string and don't want to use a regex, use `biblebook.replace()` instead of `biblebook.replaceAll()`.

Comment: @Nikita Have you tried: `biblebook = biblebook.replace("[{\"-bnumber\":\"1\",\"-bname\":\"Genesis\",\"CHAPTER\":","[");`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include `[` as a part of your regex expression, then you need to close the bracket.
`[{\"-bnumber\":\"1\",\"-bname\":\"Genesis\",\"CHAPTER\]`

But if the bracket `[` is part of your string, then you need to escape as

`\\[{\"-bnumber\":\"1\",\"-bname\":\"Genesis\",\"CHAPTER\`